# Async resolving AngularJS service that I need in future state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

In several places in my AngularJS app I need to fetch some basic value from a webservice. That is a somewhat legacy call and takes a few seconds to make. Any changes to this data is saved as soon as they are made and no other call to this is needed in the session.

I was thinking the best way was to make the call at app start, and do it in the background, later when a user would move to a dependent state it should already be resolved. I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not and two questions about this come to mind.

1) Where should I initialize the service so that it happens right of the bat, but doesn't hold back the resolving of the MainCtrl etc.

2) If a dependent state is called before the the service is fully initialized (for example refresh in a dependent state) I would need to wait for the resolve, could I grab the promise somehow at that state, even if the service already started initializing (perhaps storing the promise object somewhere)?

The dependant state has another services the depend on values from the longcalling one like this:

```
resolve: {
            value: function (serviceWithLongCall) {
                return serviceWithLongCall.call();
            },
            halfvalue: function (value, halfingservice) {
                return halfingservice.halfer(value);
            }
        }
```

Here is a fiddle that shows the problem with the long wait on the second controller, I'm trying to accomplish no wait time for second state if the user waits the 4 seconds on the main page.

http://jsfiddle.net/IngoVals/gsj6ve6o/1/

**EDIT**

```
app.factory('longcallingService',
        function ($resource, $q) {
            var thevalues = {};
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var longcallingService = {
                initialize: initialize,
                getData: getData
            }

            return longcallingService;

            function initialize() {
                $resource('api/getmy/values').get({}).$promise.then(function (data) {
                    thevalues = data;
                    deferred.resolve(thevalues);
                });
            }

            function getData() {
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });
```

I'm calling the initialize method in the `app.run`, and it works mostly as intended. The later states that resolve the `getData()` method resolve instantly if I've waited long enough.

However during app start it seems like it's waiting for the `initialize()` method. Shouldn't it just fire of API call and forget about it?

Comment: Ok, found a possible solution. Would love a peer review

http://jsfiddle.net/IngoVals/gsj6ve6o/2/

Essentially I would hold a single instance of $q and return it each call, I would only start the process and resolve it once.

Comment: Tried adding the code in the .run method, I'm calling a $resource getter, but I'm handling the promise internally in the server. It still seems to hang the rendering and wait for it to end. I though Javascript was async by default.